# How to maintain order precedence

Tags: c#, algorithm

I have couple of tasks listed in a datagrid, with their task name and duedate. I am showing all tasks based on order precedence. If the user needs to add a task in middle of datagrid, I read the selected task's precedence number, increment it, and set it as the new task's precedence number. Then I increment the precedence number of all tasks listed after the new task.

I read all tasks from the database and maintain it in an ObservableCollection .Before displaying the tasks, I sort based on order precedence.

```
       public class Task
          {
              public int TaskId { get; set; }
              public string TaskName { get; set; }
              public DateTime DueDate { get; set; }
              public int OrderPrecedence { get; set; }
          }
```

Here if one new task added to collection, I need to update all others task precendences. Is there a good way to handle the order precedence without updating other task's precedence numbers?

Comment: I don't understand the use of the word "no" in your question, but it otherwise sounds like you're asking about linked lists.

Comment: its precedence Number based on this i am sorting a collection showing in grid

Comment: What are you going to do with the data structure you need to maintain? Just insert and iterate 1 to n? Or will you need to access a task by it's order? Or maybe just pick the 'highest' task?

Comment: I'm going to edit your question to replace "no" with "number", since that seems to be your intent. I'll also try to make it sound more like idiomatic English.

Comment: I'm wondering whether you should just be sorting on due date...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of maintaining an order, could you have a Task Priority? Similar to Windows Task Priority. ie, all "High" priority tasks would run before "Normal" priority tasks. And if two tasks have the same priority, the one with the sooner DueDate would run first.

Comment: I think this is closer to the right answer. There's no point saving a value that's logically derived from all other values.